# Can we prove undefinability theorem first (using techniques that are different from Godel's) and then deduce Incompleteness from it?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, incompleteness

I asked a related question about the matter [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3636/could-incompletness-theorems-have-been-proved-by-tarski-if-g%C3%B6del-had-not-proved) in philosophy platform where it was suggested to ask a modified version of the question on Math.se

My question is, Is there any known way to prove undefinability theorem using technique different than that of Godel and then deduce Incompleteness from it?

Comment: "Techniques" is vague... having the [Diagonalization Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_lemma), Tarski's Theorem can be proved and incompleteness follows. See e.g. Peter Smith, [An Introduction to Gödel's Theorems](https://books.google.it/books?id=sCkgAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA197) (2nd ed 2013), **Ch.27 Tarski’s Theorem**, page 197-on.